# Prevent the user from going to the URL manually

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-users

I am writing a website on the Django framework

I have a user application in which authorization, registration, password change, user password reset are configured

I have an url: `auth/password_change/` that processes a view of the `PasswordChangeView` class embedded in Django with a form for changing the user's password and, if successful, redirects to the url: `auth/password_change_done/`

`auth/password_change_done/` handles the representation of the `PasswordChangeDoneView` class built into Django, which handles a template that says: *you have successfully changed your password*.

But any authorized user, even without changing the password, can manually go to the URL `auth/password_change_done/` and get the page to which the redirect should go only if the password is successfully changed

Tell me how to make it so that no one can manually get to the URL `auth/password_change_done/`, but only if the password has been successfully changed?

I tried to use `re_path`, but it has nothing to do with it at all.
I need some other way

I will be grateful to everyone

Comment: You can store the relevant record in the database (e.g. if PasswordHistory record exists for the user within last 5 minutes, allow). Alternatively, you can make an unlimited or time-restricted JWT (or any other secret), require that to be present in URL and validate for every request. I'd probably go the JWT way to make this page available for user for a fixed time amount without extra DB query, but if you already record password hash history - maybe the first solution fits better.

Comment: `no one can manually get to the URL` what do you mean by this? I type this url in the browser and what do I get? 403/404? redirect? redirect _and get the page to which the redirect should go_?

Comment: Need to get a redirect to some other page

Otherwise, it turns out that the user may get a page that says: "you have successfully changed the password", although he just entered this URL in the line

Comment: @Vasya: and what is the problem with that?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: It's very stupid if the user is given a page with a successful password change when he just goes to a certain URL address
We need to somehow forbid him to do this

Comment: @Vasya: well the internet does not make a distinction between a request made from a browser, a tool like curl, etc. The request-response protocol is just how a HTTP server works. You can look for some metaheaders, but these all can be spoofed. The password also does *not* change when the user visits that page anyway. I find it a bit bizarre investing time for such non-issue, whereas often security has a lot of other concerns to worry about.